# Problem on iterated tangent to infinity

Tags: real-analysis

It's a very simple question that my teacher proposed to me last year :

> Let the quantity have the following form $$\tan(\tan(\cdots (1)\cdots)=f^{n}(1)$$

Where we composed $n$ times the tangent function with itself and taking the variable $x=1$

Now the problem is for wich $n$ we have :
$$f^n(1)=\infty$$

Until now I was not able to found just one approach on this .

If we have a hint it would nice .
Many thanks .

Ps:Maybe it's a joke of my teacher.

Comment: For me, it does not make sense composing the tangent function with itself for its image does not fall into its domain.

Comment: @PtF Presumably, the question means, when does $f^{n-1}(1)=k\pi+\pi/2$

Comment: What does "For which $x$ we have $f^n(1)=\infty$" mean? There's no $x$ in the equality.

Comment: Thanks the problem is now complete .